# Composite index missing error when querying ASP.NET Odata to Cosmos DB

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, odata, azure-cosmosdb

Why does Cosmos db need a composite index while ordering on single field "CreatedTime" but with a $top row limiter.

Works

```
http://localhost:8000/api/candidate?$top=3
```

Works

```
http://localhost:8000/api/candidate?$orderby=CreatedTime
```

Does not work

```
http://localhost:8000/api/candidate?$top=3&$orderby=CreatedTime
```

Error

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 53cc9702-985e-46f6-9b02-e351aa7d5b4a; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The order by query does not have a corresponding composite index that it can be served from."]}
```

Querying directly on Cosmos DB works perfectly

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM c 
order by c.updatedTime desc
```